# Wiered mysqlSyntaxErrorException with mybatis-spring

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am facing very wiered issue with mybatis-spring which keep giving my mysql syntax exception

```
bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temptable AS(
                select c.tmpid,h.val' at line 4
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:368)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:163)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:95)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.mypackage.service.getValue(service.java:260)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:350)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Below is the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temptable AS(
                select c.tmpid,h.value from xyz c
                left join pqr h 
                on h.tmpid = c.tmpid
                where h.date = (select max(date) from abc where tmpid = c.tmpid)
            );
 select * from temptable;
 drop table temptable;
```

This happens only when I deploy on server. on local its working fine with no issues.

On local I am using Server version: 5.5.27-log MySQL Community Server (GPL) but on server its Server version: 5.5.44-0+deb7u1 (Debian)

I am suspecting server version issue but didn't find anything.

Below are my jar versions: 
mybatis : 3.3.0
mybatis-spring : 1.2.3
mysql : 5.1.36

its wiered in sense its working perfectly fine in local so possibility of invalid syntax is rolled out.

I also tried creating .sql file with same query and fired it on mysql command line on server and it returns perfect results.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: I don't think the parentheses are necessary.  try create table your_table_name as select name, number from other_table; instead of create table your_table_name as (select name, number from other_table)

Comment: I already tried with that syntax and still keep getting same exception.

Comment: What is there before `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` ... show the code.

Comment: Nothing. Just creating temp table and selecting from it. Whenever I have temp table creation in my query I get this error otherwise other queries works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The exception mybatis throws took me all together in different direction. The problem with my connection URL which I missed to add on server. ?allowMultiQueries=true need to be set to allow executing multiple statements.

Comment: Thanks you just saved me a bunch of time.